# How to createview django manytomany models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

been trying to save my recipe-ingredients and ingredient-measure to my recipe db.

i tried a model like this:

```
class IngredientList(models.Model):
    unit = [
        ('lb', 'pound'),
        ('oz', 'ounce'),
        ('tsp', 'teaspoon'),
        ('tbsp', 'tablespoon'),
        ('G', 'gallon'),
        ('ml', 'mililitre'),
        ('l', 'litre'),
        ('g', 'gram'),
        ('kg', 'kilogram'),

    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default='img.jpg')
    #recipes = models.ManyToManyField('Recipe', through='RecipeList')
    protein = models.FloatField()
    fat = models.FloatField()
    carb = models.FloatField()
    units = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=unit)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    return self.ingredient.name


class Recipe(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        'IngredientList', through='RecipeList')
    instructions = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    serving_size = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='recipe.jpg')
    duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipe-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class RecipeList(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(RecipeList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(IngredientList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    measurement = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe.name
```

Found this form on a stackoverflow answer:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    ingredient = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(IngredientList.objects.all())
    instructions = forms.CharField()
    count = forms.IntegerField()
    serving = forms.IntegerField()
```

and this CreateView as well:

```
class RecipeCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = "recipe/shoppinglist_form.html"
    form_class = RecipeForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        ingredient = form.cleaned_data['ingredient']
        instructions = form.cleaned_data['instructions']
        serving = form.cleaned_data['serving']

        recipe = RecipeList(name=name)
        recipe.save()
        ingredient_list = IngredientList.objects.filter(pk__in=ingredient)
        for i in ingredient_list:
            recipe.ingredients.add(i)

        return render(request, 'recipe/recipe.html')
```

When I submit, yes I do get the ingredients and the name of the recipe. However i am unable to state the measurement of each ingredient, and also the other details aren't being filled ( serving_size, instructions...)

Please someone help!

Comment: trying to find the same answer

Comment: Can you provide ```recipe.html```? Are you trying to iterate over ingredient in this template?

Comment: yes, i am hoping to view the list of ingredients, and their measurement

Comment: <div>
 <h3>{{ object.name}}</h3>
 <span class="badge badge-info">{{object.cuisine}}</span>
 <div>
  <p><strong>Ingredients: </strong></p><ul>
     {% for k in object.shoppinglist_set.all %}
     <li>{{k.ingredients.name}}<span class="badge badge-info badge-pill">{{k.measurement}} {{k.ingredients.units}}</span></li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
   </div>

   <p>Instructions: {{object.instructions}}</p>
   <p">This makes {{ object.serving_size}} meals</p>

   <p><li>Duration: {{object.duration}}</li></p>
  </div>
 </div>